# Is it possible to have 2 different values for the same property in CSS?

Tags: css

When performing an example for the purpose of testing CSS I tried the following:

Adding 2 CSS Values to the same property is not taking effect even though when being used for a single selector.

```
p{
  color: green;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-style: italic;
  font-style: bold
}
```

As of the above code is not taking effect on text for making it Italics and Bold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`font-style: bold` should be **`font-weight:bold`**

[**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)
[**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a CSS rule and repeat a property declaration.

However, the value actually used is the last one listed.

For example:

```
p {
    color: green;
    color: red;
}
```

In this example, `p` could have the color `red` since the second line over-rides the previous property declaration.

Reference: The relevant CSS specification is known as the cascading order:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

Comment: True, but in this case, he's simply using the **wrong** property.

Comment: There are two aspects to this question: (1) get the property right as you pointed out and (2) understand how the cascade deals with repeated property declarations.

Answer (score 0):

No, a property for an element always has a single value, though the value itself can have multiple parts, as in `font-family: verdana, sans-serif`, where `verdana, sans-serif` is the single value.

If a CSS rule contains several *declarations* with the same property name, the last one wins, as explained in @MarcAudet’s answer.

CSS declarations do not have cumulative effects in the sense that you could set, in a rule, `foo: bar` and then `foo: abc`, expecting this to result in a value that somehow combines `bar` and `abc`. For some properties, such cumulation might be desirable, but it’s not possible.

As explained by @Paulie_D, your practical mistake was to use a wrong property name. You need to use the correct font property name, such as `font-weight` for boldness, or, alternatively, use the [`font` shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font):

```
p {
  color: green;
  font: bold italic 100% verdana;
}
```

In this approach, you need not remember the names of the component properties. On the other hand, you need to follow the rules for the order of the values (and for required values), and they aren’t really much simpler.